# How many ancestral generations do I have?

Tags: reproduction

Following on from this question: [How many humans have been in my lineage? Is it almost the same for every human currently living?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/how-many-humans-have-been-in-my-lineage-is-it-almost-the-same-for-every-human-c#)

How many generations back do my ancestors go? Not just human ancestors, but all ancestors, right back to the first lifeform.

I recognise that there are some impossible unknowns here, so I’m looking for some kind of Fermi estimate.

Comment: sexual reproduction changed the generational thing so you have perhaps 1 - 4  billion sexually reproductive generations since your precambrian times, if you have an average 1 to 4 generations per year, seasonally, on average. since 4 billion years, zircons from australia have isotopes of oxygen that suggest life, and stromatolites date from <3.7, so we are talking about 4-400 billion prokariote and eurkariote zygote meioses.