# Would it be more genetically efficient to have shorter lifespans?

Tags: evolution, lifespan

If, for example, humans had an average lifespan of, say, 30 years, and we reached sexual maturity at age 10, then we could "evolve" more quickly and theoretically "weed-out" more genetic diseases because we would live for shorter times, hence more natural selection.

> Why don't we continually evolve for *shorter* lifespans (or do we)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does evolution not make our life longer?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/why-does-evolution-not-make-our-life-longer)

Comment: @Remi.b, The linked 'duplicate' asks for the opposite. This is not a duplicate from my point of view.

Comment: This question is conceptually similar: [*Why are the fertility rates of large predators kept low?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28300/why-are-the-fertility-rates-of-large-predators-kept-low/28333#28333) (~why isn't trait X evolving since it should have a positive effect), and the issue of life history tradeoffs found in the answers is relevant here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Extremely briefly, we do not evolve shorter lifespans because [natural selection does not act for the good of the species.](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/misconceptions_faq.php#b4)

As an interesting historical aside, August Weismann proposed essentially the idea you are suggesting in 1889, in his *Essays upon heredity and kindred biological problems.* Within a few years, however, he backed away from this hypothesis.