# Modeling and Predicting Squirrel Populations

Tags: theoretical-biology, population-biology

I was recommended to come here from the MathSE site. Here is the question:

I am interested in modeling the growth of the Eastern Fox squirrel population in Los Angeles, not only in terms of numbers but also in overall territory. The site iNaturalist has a wonderful database of [sitings](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations?place_id=962&subview=map&taxon_id=46020) at my disposal, but I am unfamiliar with the mathematical model(s) that I'd need to use to model and predict their growth and territory.

I have taken a quick look at a paper on [regular migration](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsos.180438) and [this BiologySE post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45716/guide-to-learning-about-population-biology-ecology-dynamics-for-a-non-biolog). Would this be what I am looking for? Or does the question I'm asking require something else? Thank you in advance for the help.

While the eastern fox squirrel is not migratory, I assume the models from the migration paper can be abstracted for my purposes. Perhaps I am wrong.

Some more information as requested by a commenter:

I am completely new to the theory of population biology. The only data I have is from the iNaturalist site, which has geotags of sitings and # of sitings. I am interested in finding out how the Eastern Fox squirrel population has grown over the past few decades, and how their territory shapes up to that of the native Western Gray squirrel. There has been commentary in [Washington](https://conservationnw.org/news-updates/the-imperiled-western-gray-squirrel-needs-to-be-reclassified-as-endangered-to-enable-long-term-conservation-efforts/) and [NorCal](https://baynature.org/2019/05/28/are-fox-squirrels-replacing-gray-squirrels-in-california/) about the shrinking populations of the latter, but I haven't found anything for Los Angeles. This is why I am asking here -- to see whether Eastern Fox squirrels outnumber Western Grays in a significant way (don't take 'significant' in a technical sense).

Comment: Welcome to the Biology SE. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Lets get some things cleared up - please edit the answers into your question. How much population biology (theoretical or otherwise) do you know? How much do you know about the population as it stands now - what sort of data do you have? What do you want to find out? Also, are they migratory? if not, why do you think a paper on migration will help?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/114138/61455, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4866740/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: You might try to start with log growth, then use iNaturalist data to see if there are geographical areas of overlap in Eastern Fox and Western Gray sightings. If so, check out Lotka-Volterra to assess the competitive interactions.